# MySql DateDiff does not return negative

Tags: mysql, datediff

I need to return negative time if exceded.

For example:

```
 SELECT 
CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())) / 24), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())), 24), ' hours ', MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())), ' minutes') AS RemainigTime,
FROM kartica
```

This should return

> -7 days 10 hours

... But I get

> 7 days 10 hours

How to display negative?

...

Comment: Your title says `datediff`, but the question uses `timediff`. `timediff` does return negative, but `HOUR(TIMEDIFF(...))` returns positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll will give you a difference without comparison bigger/smaller, so:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    IF('2017-05-19 12:32:11' < NOW(), '-', ''),
    FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())) / 24), ' days ',
    MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())), 24), ' hours ',
    MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2017-05-19 12:32:11', NOW())), ' minutes'
) AS RemainigTime
FROM kartica
```

Answer (score 0):

That's is because the diference is 7 day, 10 hours, always, there is no -7 days ;). You need to cast the result to another type like REAL